# regular expression for a pattern of 8 characters seperated by a hypen

Tags: regex, shell

I wanted a regular expression for a pattern like the following,

```
1. F639-180C
2. 245A-14F0
3. 319A-15E4
4. A45C-15E5
```

As I have observed, there will be 8 alphanumeric characters and a hyphen in between. The pattern that I thought was `"[A-Za-z]|[0-9]{4}"-"[A-Za-z]|[0-9]{4}"`, I am not sure if this will work fine.

Comment: Hi  Fazlin, tried my pattern but didn't work. [:alnum:] also didn't work for my surprise. is there any other solution??

Comment: @Arun, check my answer below, it's explicit, it think it solves your thing easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regexp was almost correct, if you want to use it with the explicit enumeration of chars, you may do it like this:

```
/[A-Za-z0-9]{4}\-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}/g
```

or to make it even simpler, it may turn to

```
/\w{4}\-\w{4}/g
```

where `\w{4}` match any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. I was not sure if you need a **global** flag - but you can remove it yourself, depending on the task.

Keep in mind, that depending on what regexp you are using, it might turn to an alternate way to match alpanumeric letters
`[[:alpha:]]{4}-[[:alpha:]]{4}`

__

**Improvement**: as it was outlined in comments, you probably need to grab only **HEX codes**, so the regular expression has to take into consideration **not** the whole set of chars from A to Z, but only HEX codes: `[A-Fa-f0-9]`

Comment: I'm guessing they are hexadecimal numbers, so you could do a minor change and use `/[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}/g` to add check that they're valid numbers (and you don't need to escape the hyphen).

Comment: your are right @ClasG, but I prefer explicit escaping of tricky chars, which might be treated as interval sometimes :) I chosen a safe way.

Comment: Hey, This worked fine. Thanks for the solution Farside. :) Thanks everyone for the help!! :)